# Can't deploy on https://wallet.ethereum.org: DAO

Tags: the-dao, tokens

I'm writing Decentralised Application.
I've added function vote() an function changeName().
After that my code can't compile on wallet.ethereum.org.
Though remix.ethereum.org shows no mistakes.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract SimpleDAO {

  string public name;   
  string public symbol;  
  uint8 public decimals;

  uint256 public totalSupply; 

   mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf; 

   mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;  

    uint8 public minVotes = 6;
   string public proposalName;
   bool public voteActive = false;
  struct Votes{
     uint256 current;
     uint numberOfVotes;
   }
   Votes public election;

   event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);

   event Approve(address from, address to, uint256 value);

    function SimpleDao() public { 

     decimals = 0;

    totalSupply = 1000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;

    name = "SimpleDAO";

    symbol = "tDAO"; 
  }

 function  _transfer (address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal{
  require (_to != 0x0);
 require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
 require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
 balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
 balanceOf[_to] += _value;
  Transfer(_from,_to,_value);
}
 function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
   _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
 }

   function transferFrom (address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public { 

  require(_value <= allowance[_from][_to]);  
   allowance[_from][_to] -= _value;  

  _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}
   function approve(address _to, uint256 _value) public{

   allowance[msg.sender][_to] = _value; 

   Approve(msg.sender, _to, _value);
 }  

  function newName (string _proposalName)  public{
     require(!voteActive);
     proposalName = _proposalName;
     voteActive = true;
  }
  function vote(bool _vote) public {
       require(voteActive);
       if (_vote) {
         election.current += uint256(balanceOf[msg.sender]);            
         }
       else {
         election.current      -= uint256(balanceOf[msg.sender]);
        } 
         election.numberOfVotes += uint256(balanceOf[msg.sender]);  
      }
   function changeName() public{
     require(voteActive);
    require(election.numberOfVotes >= minVotes);
     if (election.current > 0) {
         name = proposalName;  
      }    
       election.numberOfVotes = 0; 
       election.current = 0;
       voteActive = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Are there any compiler errors? How do you know it won't compile?

Comment: my code can't compile on wallet.ethereum.org.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that it should be deployed in mist, not on wallet.ethereum.org